# How does one figure out how fast water is moving through a water intake on a dam?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, measurements, flow

Say the dam is Hoover dam for example.  The intake is where the water flows in to turn the turbines that generate electricity.  I want to know if there is an equation that describes the speed of the water.  I plan to use this equation to figure out how much energy any given dam can generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following image,
[image]

we have some fluid volume, $V$, having density $\rho$ and traveling at a velocity $v$ along a pipe with some cross-sectional area $A$. The rate at which the water flows through the pipe is called the [volumetric flow rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_flow_rate). This is given by,
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}\equiv Q=\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf A
$$
where $V$ is the volume of the fluid, $Q$ the flow rate, $\mathbf v$ is the velocity of the flow and $\mathbf A$ the cross-sectional area of the flow.

If you know the *density* of the fluid, then the [mass flow rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate) is
$$
\rho\frac{dV}{dt}\equiv\dot m=\rho\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf A
$$

Note that while $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf A$ are both vectors, you probably can assume a one-dimensional flow, i.e., $Q=vA$, to approximate the energy.